# How to tie Typeahead.js suggestions to a cross domain data source?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, typeahead.js

Title says it all.

I tried using a remote source, on the url (which is on another domain) and got back the following message:

> ```
> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
> http://www..../argument?callback=urlHandler. No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. Origin 'http://localhost:5000' is therefore not allowed
> access.
> ```

**Relevant Code**

```
var films = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: function(d) { return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.value); },
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  remote: {url: "http://www..../%QUERY?callback=urlHandler",
           ajax: $.ajax({type:'GET',dataType:'jsonp',jsonp:'jsonp'})                                    
  }
});
```

Update: It seems that the problem is with CORS issues. And the `$.ajax` settings object's dataType being set to `jsonp` is not respected. The comments below have more information.

**EDIT:** I found a fix! The question now becomes explaining why this worked.

So when I changed the url to `http://www....?callback=?` which actually made it load the response of the GET call as a JSONP object. Shouldn't the AJAX `dataType` and `jsonp` attributes have covered this?

Comment: Can you post a fiddle to demo your problem

Comment: If your data changes locally, then you need to destroy and re-initialize the typeahead object (https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#jquerytypeaheaddestroy). If it changes on the server, just use a `remote:` data source.

Comment: @NitzanShaked Could you take another look at the question and the body? I edited it as I ran into problems using remote.

Comment: Well you have CORS issues. I am not familiar with Bloodhound, but you basically have 3 options: (1) use jsonp, if bloodhound and FB API support that (2) use local FB SDK (3) proxy the call to FB from your server, and use `remote:` to your proxying endpoint. Hope that's clear enough.

Comment: In the Ajax object above, I did put down datatype as 'jsonp'. I'm not using FB but I understand that I can proxy it to another route. I'll give that a shot

Comment: For me the url suffix "callback=?" is the only required change to make cross domain work.

Comment: Yep, I mentioned that in the EDIT up there. I'm not sure why though, so if you can explain why, and put it as an answer, I'll give you the points.

Comment: An answer to this question can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23394245/using-typeahead-with-google-custom-search-engine/23451344#23451344)

Comment: Hey Ben you should post the link or the answer within it as an answer for future reference for example I found this question by accident if its been solved we should have an answer as stack overflow answers are to be used by others

Answer (score 4):

This is kind of old but the method of accomplishing jsonp with Twitter Typeahead has changed since this question was asked and this answer comes up as one of the top results when searching for "twitter typeahead jsonp"

Any changes to the transport settings in typeahead should be done via the prepare function in the Bloodhound constructor.

```
var search = new Bloodhound({
            datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
            queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
            // `states` is an array of state names defined in "The Basics"
            //local: states,
            remote: {
                url: 'http://www.myserver.com/my_search_endpoint/SearchTerm=%searchValue',
                prepare: function(query, settings) {
                    settings.dataType = "jsonp"
                    settings.url = settings.url.replace('%searchValue', query)
                    return settings;
                }
            }
        });
```

the prepare function should return a settings object. See here for more details: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/bloodhound.md#remote

You will also need to make sure that you replace the wildcard value yourself in the prepare function.

```
             remote: {
                url: 'http://www.myserver.com/my_search_endpoint/SearchTerm=%searchValue',
                wildcard: '%searchValue'
             }
```

will no longer work once you specify prepare.

Answer (score 0):

You can make cross domain requests using the XMLHttpRequest object. This is done using something called "Cross Origin Resource Sharing". See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Very simply put, when the request is made to the server the server can respond with a Access-Control-Allow-Origin header which will either allow or deny the request. The browser needs to check this header and if it is allowed then it will continue with the request process. If not the browser will cancel the request.

You can find some more information and a working example here: http://www.leggetter.co.uk/2010/03/12/making-cross-domain-javascript-requests-using-xmlhttprequest-or-xdomainrequest.html

JSONP is an alternative solution, but you could argue it's a bit of a hack.